# Atmega328 and 4Digit 7 Segment ghost blinking!

Tags: atmega328

I hooked up 4 7Seg leds (CC) with NPN transistors on the cathode of each digit. I am using 74HC595 shift register connected in the circuit in a pretty common fashion. The code I am running is the basic scanning code for the 7seg. The problem is that I see the scanned numbers on other LED digits too. Attached is the image. I call them "ghosts". The circuit I am using has an Atmega328 with an internal 8MHz Osc. The resistors on the segments are 220Ohm and 4 BC547's on the cathodes of the digits with 1kOhm resistors on their base.
[image]

**below is the code:**

```
void loop() {
 
      cathode_high(); // blank the screen
  
      break_number(number);
      
      display_number();
     delay(1);

    
}

void break_number(int num) { // seperate the input number into 4 single digits

  first_digit = num / 1000;
  digits[0] = first_digit;  

  int first_left = num - (first_digit * 1000);
  second_digit = first_left / 100; 
  digits[1] = second_digit;
  int second_left = first_left - (second_digit * 100); 
  third_digit = second_left / 10; 
  digits[2] = third_digit; 
  fourth_digit = second_left - (third_digit * 10);
  digits[3] = fourth_digit;
  
  
}

void display_number() { //scanning
   
  cathode_high(); 
  digitalWrite(latch, LOW); 
  shiftOut(data, clk, LSBFIRST, numbers[digits[count]]); 
  digitalWrite(CAS[count], HIGH); 
  digitalWrite(latch, HIGH); 
  count++; 
  if (count == 4) {
    count = 0;
  }
}

void cathode_high() { //turn off all 4 digit
  digitalWrite(CA_1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(CA_2, LOW);
  digitalWrite(CA_3, LOW);
  digitalWrite(CA_4, LOW);
}
```

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanx in advance!

Comment: PNP on each cathode?! Surely you mean NPN...? You'd use PNP with a common anode, not a common cathode display.

Comment: Oh yes... I am sorry. 547 is an NPN.

Comment: If you only ever display one digit (never increment count) do you still see ghosting on that digit?

Comment: Could you measure the voltage on the Cathode pins when they're supposedly turned off? My guess is the BC547's do not completely turn off current through the display, or turn off very slowly, which explains the "ghost" when switching between digits. If you have an oscilloscope you could watch the voltage on the BC547's collector.

Comment: @Majenko Thanx for the effort. It is solved.

Comment: @StarCat It was a coding error. Its done now. Thanx anyway!!

Comment: @jsotola I have corrected it. Thanx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You change cathodes (digits) before latching in the new data. So for a spit second the data for the previous digits is shown on the current digit.

Swapping `digitalWrite(CAS[count], HIGH);` and `digitalWrite(latch, HIGH);` should fix that.

Comment: Bingo!! It worked. Thank You!

Comment: Glad it worked. `digitalWrite` is relatively slow. Thought I've had "ghosting" with direct port manipulation too.

Comment: Is there a way we can turn On/Off a full digit using the scanning method with 74hc595? As far as I understand, we cannot because the `display_number()` function is switching the digit pins already for scan.

Comment: I'd add one more element in the `numbers` array for the "no digit", with all segments off. To turn of a digit, you can then set the digit to the "number" `10`.

Comment: Well, I understood the first part (adding a number to the array) and in my case the 7th element would render all digits blank, but unclear on the second part. And specially "number" `10`

Comment: The `numbers` array is a lookup table for how to display a certain number (that is; which segments to turn on. Where index `0` gives you the segments that need to be on to show the **character** "0" on your 7-segment display. Index `1` for character "1" etc. I'd add an index `10` at the end for the empty character. The to set a digit to blank, use something like `digits[1]=10;`. Why did you `numbers` array only have 6 elements? I was expecting it to have 10 (indexes 0..9).

Comment: You could even add more indexes for the characters "AbCdEF-_" (which are about all the characters you can make on a 7-segment display).

Comment: Aahh I got you! Sorry I got confused in `digit numbers`. Earlier I had 4digits but now they are 6. So, had to add another element in the `numbers` array....great let me try it. I am making a reverse time counter for a machine. 6 digits mean, **H** **M** **S** . It is working good only I just wanted to blink the digit while setting the countdown time.

Comment: Ahh, now I get it. Note that you also have a decimal point. You could also use those to indicate a different mode (e.g. "time setting mode"). Just a thought.

Comment: Hey, Sorry I got stuck somewhere else. I have this on my mind too. Will try and get back. Thanx for all the support again.